# What's the more performant database design for query speed and write overhead when storing many boolean columns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, performance, postgresql-performance

**Setting the scene**

I have a PostgreSQL 11 database running on a very fast 64core, 10 SSD HW RAID 10 server. In the database I need to create a table with a couple of million rows, let's call it `cars`. The rows will see very frequent updates and even more frequent read. Very heavy usage. The cars have many different equipment attributes like `has_electrical_side_mirrors`, `has_automatic_gearbox`, `has_gps_navigation` etc. etc. About 150 of them, all boolean. On top of this there is gonna be something like 40 other columns of strings and integers. I want a design specifically for storing those 150 boolean values.

**My ideas**

I can basically see a couple of designs of which I think two will be superior from a performance and storage overhead point of view:

1. Add 150 boolean columns
2. Add a join table with equipment
3. Add an intarray column with equipment ids (`23=has_gps_navigation` etc.)
4. Add a JSONb column with key/value equipment (`{'has_gps_navigation' => true} etc.`)

Of those above I think the choice stands between option 1. and 3.

**Why I don't think option 2. and 4. is a good idea**

Option 2. in my experience is gonna give too much performance overhead on queries (I need < 200ms response time on queries on cars that has this or that equipment). I think option 4. is very similar to 3. but 4. will also have a larger disk space overhead than 3. if I store all values like `{'has_gps_navigation' => true}` etc. because I would have the key names stored in the db.

So down to option 1. and 3. I guess - any strong opinions otherwise?

**My concerns about option 1. and 3.**

My main concern with option 1. is that I would have to create 150 indexes or somewhere around that, to make queries performant. That sounds like the table, to my knowledge, will see a huge overhead on write performance. The other concern I have with option 1. is that it's gonna be a pain adding new equipment, having to create a column and an index every time.

My main concern with option 2. is that I have little experience with using postgresql intarrays. How performant are they in comparison in this situation and what kind of indexes should I use? As far as I can read, I can cover indexing of all equipment by just having a single index on that `equipment_item_ids`-column. I can easily create some logic in my application that maps the strings of `has_gps_navigation` to an integer of `23`, my idea is then, if the car has a specific piece of equipment, add the id of it to the array.

Comment: How many rows are you expecting to store?

Comment: "create a table with a couple of million rows" :-)

Comment: Work out the common fields selected and use compound indexes for those, starting with common fields.

Comment: Did you actually test option 2? Don't underestimate the database when it comes to choosing a good execution plan. Especially if you always check those boolean values for a single car. A where condition would most certainly use an index on the car ID in the join table which in turn will only return at most 150 rows. Even as part of a join I would expect that to be doable in substantially less than 200ms.

Comment: Can you show us some example queries? What type of conditions are you expecting?

Comment: Thanks for the follow ups. I didn't test option 2. no. It was just my experience with joins on large tables that lead to this. Also, I forgot to mention, that option 2. will require a lot more changes in my application, than any of the three other options, so I really wouldn't prefer that one - I know it's a bit silly. What do you people think about that idea in option 3.? Is it bad? I personally think it would be quite elegant, keeping an array of integers that each represent a kind of equipment. If the car has that equipment item, it's corresponding ID is in the array, else it's not.

Comment: If you're not afraid of bit computing, the `varbit` type would be the more compact to store 150 bits. With frequent updates, compacity is important.

Comment: The very frequent updates doesn't really mesh with your example of cars.  How often does any particular car gain or loss GPS, airbags, full-size spare tires, etc?  Is it really updates that are frequent, or just inserts and deletes?

Comment: Do the queries only test for simple containment, or do you also have tests for non-containment, or complex booleans expressions including parentheses, NOT, OR?

Comment: @jjanesYou are right, the writes often does NOT go to the booleans themselfs but to some other e.g. timestamp column on the cars. It's my understanding though, that this might be heavy to indexes on other columns too...? As for the usage of the flags in the queries. I think all of your examples will be relevant to be able to support.

Comment: As others have asked, the primary question seems to be: are you just returning these booleans or are you querying on these booleans and how?   Select all cars with heated_GPS, electrical_hood_adjusters, and no more than two of (airbags, seatbelts, 8trackplayer and froyomachine)?

Comment: I will be filtering by those values too. In arbitrary combinations